# Video wont play in Galaxy Note 2

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video

I'm working on a project in which the html should play right after the user clicks an image, this is the JavaScript code in which we handle it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container").on("click", ".video-tile a.feedModal", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        video = $(this).hide().next().show().find("video")[0];
        video.addEventListener('canplay',function(){video.play();},false);
        videoAutoPlay(video);
    });
});
```

---

```
function videoAutoPlay(video){
    if(video.paused){
        video.load();
        video.play();
    }
}
```

This works for every other device, except for the Galaxy Note 2. How can I make this work? I have been stuck in this for about 3 days and can't find any suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the `videoAutoPlay` function or the `canplay` event listener? Just call `video.play()` directly in the click handler. Won't the following work?

```
$(function() {
    $("#container").on("click", ".video-tile a.feedModal", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().next().show().find("video")[0].play();
    });
});
```

To answer your *actual* question, your original code will work on the Note 2 if you take out the `video.load()` call. At least it did on my Note 2 in this working sample:
http://jsbin.com/qoyus/1

I had to guess on your html structure, since you didn't include that in the question.

Comment: Actually, the code at first was in that way, but didn't worked for the GS3, so I changed it and ended up looking as the code I posted, at the end I did it in another way nad now it works. But thanks anyway.